# Eloquent Where using CASE WHEN and withMin()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

I have a query like this:

```
Product::withMin('promotions as promotion_price', 'promotion_products.price')
  ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN promotion_price IS NULL THEN sale_price ELSE promotion_price END ASC')
  ->get();
```

the query result like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Asus Nvidia RTX 3080",
    "sale_price": 42500000,
    "promotion_price": 10000
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "title": "Microsoft 365 Business Basic",
    "sale_price": 39100,
    "promotion_price": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Test Paimon s",
    "sale_price": 99999,
    "promotion_price": 50000
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Asus Nvidia RTX 3090",
    "sale_price": 56500000,
    "promotion_price": 50000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Test Product",
    "sale_price": 990000,
    "promotion_price": 50000
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "title": "Microsoft 365 Apps",
    "sale_price": 129000,
    "promotion_price": null
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "title": "Microsoft 365 Business Standard",
    "sale_price": 156400,
    "promotion_price": null
  }
]
```

then I want to add some condition if promotion_price is null use sale_price to filter. I try use this query:

```
whereRaw('CASE WHEN promotion_price IS NULL THEN sale_price ELSE promotion_price END BETWEEN 0 AND 20000000')
```

and it said "Unknown Column 'promotion_price'". Any solution for this? thanks~

Comment: try     ->havingRaw('CASE WHEN promotion_price IS NULL THEN sale_price>0 AND sale_price<20000000 ELSE  promotion_price>0 AND promotion_price<20000000 END') instead of whereRaw

Comment: ah very nice.. thanks again you're very helpful (y)

Comment: is above code producing desired result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [havingRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw) instead of where condition

```
Product::withMin('promotions as promotion_price', 'promotion_products.price')
        ->havingRaw('CASE WHEN promotion_price IS NULL THEN sale_price=>0 AND sale_price<=20000000 ELSE promotion_price=>0 AND promotion_price<=20000000 END')
        ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN promotion_price IS NULL THEN sale_price ELSE promotion_price END ASC')
        ->get();
```